# Should Ribbon be used on the web?

Tags: web-app, guidelines, ribbon, editor

I'm designing a web application which has a large number of commands and customizations, with many more to come in the future.

I've read a number of things on usage of the ribbon, from MS's guidelines, to a long series of videos by the original Office 2007 designer on their motivations for doing so, etc.

From what I can tell, you should consider a ribbon if you have a large number of commands, and a large number of commands tied to a specific context for document creation. That I believe I have.

As a side note, I don't EXACTLY have a document creation scenario. I have a document creation  scenario (RTF level, not full-on MS Office level) surrounded by a larger data structuring and navigation scenario. It seems that the ribbon is still appropriate here but it seems worth mentioning.

However, what I haven't really seen is whether or not it's considered bad practice to use a ribbon UI for a web application for some reason I'm unaware of. Is it? Are there web-specific pitfalls I should be aware of?

Comment: Native Sharepoint websites use the ribbon. Then again, it's Microsoft. Example [here](http://www19.sp2010.examples.stores.advantrics.com/SitePages/Home.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building [RIA](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Internet_application&ei=TrH8UfrNGfGN4gSuyYCQBA&usg=AFQjCNFsuDFr2pGmnSWIpeDrVti-waCTNA&bvm=bv.50165853,d.bGE) with lots of features you have to use ribbon :). According to  [this discussion](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8238/is-microsofts-ribbon-ui-really-that-great-from-a-usability-perspective):

> One of the main drivers behind the Ribbon was discoverability of new
>   functions. This was driven by research conducted by Microsoft that
>   indicated that a large number of most requested features for Word
>   actually already existed in the product; the user simply didn't know
>   where to find it.

There is also another point of view: [Microsoft Concedes That The Ribbon Isn't Intuitive](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2009/08/microsoft-concedes-that-the-ribbon-isnt-intuitive/)

I would say ribbon may help, but you should be careful, because it is so easy to add some visual noise instead of valuable functionality.

Comment: Discoverability? Ribbon? If Discoverability and Ribbon were people, they would be duelling each other viciously with axes and spears.

Comment: That article about the ribbon being not intuitive is more about the Office 2007 button that's since been abandoned not being intuitive. They are really 2 separate concerns. One doesn't need the other to exist.

Comment: However, that other link has some really good stuff at it. I can't upvote yet on this board, but you win.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there are any web-specific considerations regarding the use of the ribbon. One somewhat relevant factor is that the ribbon is well-designed for the use of keyboard shortcuts which isn't as common on the web as on the desktop, but otherwise I think that all the usual considerations apply.

Actually Balsamiq uses a ribbon-like interface with much success. It's not exactly the standard ribbon, since the top-level menu is also present, and the "ribbon" part only lets you select controls, but overall it's the same concept.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that this is much like a ribbon type interface. It's a menu with a tabbed toolbar. A ribbon doesn't just have a tabbed toolbar with multiple buttons on each toolbar, it has multiple panels each with multiple controls on each toolbar.

Comment: Um... What's the difference? :) Tabs are panels and buttons are controls. A ribbon is precisely a tabbed toolbar, nothing more. Beyond that the difference is graphics.

Comment: Ribbon is a hodge-podge of panels **without** a systematic menu.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "It's not exactly the standard ribbon, since the top-level menu is also present"... Besides, in MS Office they still have the menu under the Office button.

Comment: The point about keyboard shortcuts being important to the ribbon but also web-foreign was very useful.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with a ribbon on a website is the wide range of devices you (might) need to account for.  The obvious problem is it won't work well on a phone size device, the the other problem is the size of a pixel unit (css px, or device pixel) varies greatly depending on the device.  I've seen apps that work fine on an iPad but on an iPad mini become 20% smaller and that 20% makes a big usability difference (on *some* apps).

Ribbons strike be as being size sensitive: if the elements are too big it becomes clumsy and space inefficient, too small and the elements become hard to *read* and click.  This might not be an issue if you're only concerned about the desktop, I don't think the size of device pixels vary as much there.

I any case I think a ribbon can be as effective in a website as in a native application, but the technical challenges may be greater (or maybe just different), especially around sizing and scaling.

Comment: Ribbons are very "responsive" to screen/window size. a lot of effort was invested in resizing and relocating elements on it. You can try and see for yourself. Therefore, I think it can manage responsive design even in a Smartphone.

Comment: @AsafBO - We still don't have nearly the precision for web layout that we do in a native app.  For instance, determining the exact size of a pixel is still problematic on the web, but has been a non-issue in native apps for 25 years.